# Trying to include a simple module - can't get it to work Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to include a simple module I made, and it is not working.

From my **index.html** page, I am including this file:

**login-view-model.js**

```
import {localStorageService} from '../shared/local-storage-module.js';

// Login View Model

var LoginViewModel = function () {

    self = this;
    this.token = ko.observable();

    this.email = ko.observable("john@gmail.com");
    this.password = ko.observable("12345");

    self.submit = function() {
        (async () => {
            const rawResponse = await fetch('http://localhost/chitra-admin/api/user/', {
              method: 'POST',
              mode: 'cors',
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({email: self.email(), password: self.password()})
            });

            const content = await rawResponse.json();

            if(content.response.id){
                self.token(content.response.token);
                localStorageService.save('token', self.token());
                alert(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
            }

            console.log(content.request.token);

          })(); 
    }

}; // End View Model


// Helper Functions For Fetching Data
function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}



ko.applyBindings(new LoginViewModel());
```

And I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I can't see where I am going wrong. My **local-storage-module.js** is about as simple as you can get:

```
const localStorageService = {

    save: function(key, val){
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, val);
    }

}



export {localStorageService} ;
```

I know the function is not practical, but I am learning. I eventually will include more complex modules, but I can't even get this simple one to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: why not just `export default localStorageService`

Comment: Where is this error coming from? Which line?

Comment: @YannickK, the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpcted token {` error comes from the `JSON.parse` method, which is called deep within `rawResponse.json()`  No doubt the JSON being parsed is malformed.  Often happens when two JSON objects get concatenated without delimiters, like `{obj:1} {obj:2}`  The second object will cause a SyntaxError.

Comment: ...also can happen when you don't check the HTTP status code or Content-Type from the response to your your fetch and wind up parsing the body of a failed request (such as 404 or 500, which may return a non-json response) instead of the expected body of a successful request (200)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this :

In local-storage-module.js instead of `export {localStorageService} ;` add `module.exports = localStorageService` and in login-view-model.js do `const localStorageService = require('../shared/local-storage-module.js')`

It is a bit old school but it will work in pure JS. :)

Comment: And please try to avoid self = this; Instead use arrow function for submit.